# How to add 1 button per row in telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using `Telegraf` for make a telegram bot, actually I'm a newbie and I would like to know how can I add one button per row, this is my code:

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')
const Markup = require('telegraf/markup')
const bot = new Telegraf('my id')

bot.start(ctx =>
    ctx.reply(
        `Welcome`,

            Markup.inlineKeyboard([
                Markup.callbackButton('', 'like'),
                Markup.callbackButton('', 'dislike')
            ]).extra()
    ));

bot.startPolling();
```

the result display two button on the same line, how can I add one button per row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')
const Markup = require('telegraf/markup')
const bot = new Telegraf('my id')

bot.start(ctx =>
    ctx.reply(
        `Welcome`,

            Markup.inlineKeyboard([
                [Markup.callbackButton('', 'like')],
                [Markup.callbackButton('', 'dislike')]
            ]).extra()
    ));

bot.startPolling();
```

Comment: thanks this works! could you please suggest me a good resource to learn how to use properly telegrafjs? I found the documentation not really easy to understand